# Embedding a live updated webpage inside of my webpage

Tags: embed, live

I'm having trouble getting this webpage to embed. I have no problem with embedding static pages, however when I attempt to embed the webpage my client requested, I get a 'The connection was reset' error. I believe I'm getting this because the site is constantly updating to real time stats. I understand it may bog down the site, however there is not much else on the page I want to upload to, so I'm not really worried about the load time.

Code:

```html
<embed src="//www.live.deckmonitoring.com/?id=solwatt_llc" style="width:500px; height: 300px;">
```